# Custom Javascript not working?

Tags: jquery, javascript

Basically I want the effect to look as it does [here](http://tympanus.net/Development/SidebarTransitions/)

But mine won't do the effect I currently have a button but it won't activate the effect for the menu to pop open.

site that I'm using to test it on [here](http://chocobento.x10.mx/wp/)

Any help would be appreciated.

I think the script classie.js which changes div's classes isn't working but I can't figure out why

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few problems but the main one is when sidebarEffects.js is loaded the HTML it's looking for doesn't exist yet. So...

```
var container = document.getElementById( 'st-container' )
// and
buttons = Array.prototype.slice.call( document.querySelectorAll( '#st-trigger-effects > button' ) )
```

are both empty when the script is run.

Easiest way to fix it is to put your `<script>` tags right before the close of your `<body>` tags instead of in the `<head>`. If you're including these files into your theme manually, no problem, just stick them in your theme's equivalent to `footer.php`. If you're enqueueing them, see the $in_footer param here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script

You also have two containers with the `id="st-trigger-effects"`. See here: https://html5.validator.nu/?doc=http%3A%2F%2Fchocobento.x10.mx%2Fwp%2F

Comment: So if I enqueue it into the footer it would solve it right?

Comment: `wp_enqueue_script( 'Sidebar-Effects', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/sidebarEffects.js', $in_footer, true );`
, this isn't working though. @Will

Comment: Looks like you have the syntax wrong.  Try, `wp_enqueue_script( 'Sidebar-Effects', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/sidebarEffects.js', false, '1.0', true)`

Comment: thanks so much! I see what you meant by entering it wrong XD @Will